# Not able to create Mimemesage in javax email

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am creating a project which sends emails to random number of users.
There is a separate function who calls sendemail method.
What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.java.quartz.job;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendEmail 
{
      private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "mail.yandex.com.au";
      private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "no-reply@abc.com.au";
      private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD = "abc";
      private static  String cmpname= "",replyto="";
      public static int tolength=0;
      public static int bcclength=0;
      public static int cclength=0;

    public static void sendmail2(List <String> receiver,List<String> cclist,List<String> bcclist ,String message,String Subject,String from) 
    {
        try {
          System.out.println("Sending Mail from ::"+from+ "to :: "+receiver);
          postMail2(receiver,cclist,bcclist,message,Subject, from);
          System.out.println("Mail sent successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Exception in SendBookingMailRequest - - -" + 
            e.getMessage());
        }
      }

  public static void postMail2(List <String> recipient,List<String> cclist,List<String> bcclist, String subject, String message, String from)
  {
    try {
          System.out.println("NEW111q1");

          Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
          props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
          props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
          props.put("mail.debug", "false");
          props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
          System.out.println("to 1 :: ");
          Authenticator auth= new SMTPAuthenticator();

          System.out.println("to 2 :: props "+props+ " auth :: "+auth );
      Session session1 = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
      System.out.println("to:: 3"+session1 );

      ---- No logs after this ----

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session1);

      System.out.println("to:: 4"+msg);    
      InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(SMTP_AUTH_USER,cmpname);
      System.out.println("to:: 5"+addressFrom);
      InternetAddress[] addresses = InternetAddress.parse(replyto);
      System.out.println("to:: 6"+addresses);
      msg.setReplyTo(addresses);

      System.out.println("to:: " + recipient);
      msg.setFrom(addressFrom);
      System.out.println("send by :: "+cmpname);
      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(cmpname));
      String strrecipient = String.join(",", recipient);
      String ccstrrecipient=String.join(",", cclist);
      String bccstrrecipient=String.join(",", bcclist);

      msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, strrecipient);
      msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccstrrecipient);
      msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccstrrecipient);


    Address Toarr[] = msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
    Address bccarr[]=msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC);
    Address ccarr[]=msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC);
    tolength=Toarr.length;
    bcclength=bccarr.length;
    cclength=ccarr.length;
    System.out.println("tolength:: "+tolength+"bcclength :: "+bcclength+" cclength:: "+cclength);
      msg.setSubject(subject);
      msg.setContent(message, "text/html");
      System.out.println("Message :: "+msg);
      //Transport.send(msg);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Error While Authenticating For Sending MAil ::" + 
        ex.getMessage());
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator 
        {

            public PasswordAuthentication getpasswordAuthentication()

            {
                String username = SMTP_AUTH_USER;
                String password = SMTP_AUTH_PWD;
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        }
}
```

I am creating `cclist` and `bcclist` here in this code and this list is sent by another code. There is no logging after the `System.out.println("to:: 3"+session1 );`

Even I am not getting any error when I run this code on the system.
Following are logs for the above code:

> Sending Mail from ::info@cbdmovers.co.nzto :: [abc@gmail.com]
>   NEW111q1
>   to 1 ::
>   to 2 :: props {mail.transport.protocol=smtp, mail.debug=false, mail.smtp.port=25, mail.smtp.auth=true, mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true, mail.smtp.host=mail.yandex.com.au} auth :: com.java.quartz.job.SendEmail$SMTPAuthenticator@1b6124f1
>   to:: 3javax.mail.Session@3d9b30bf

Comment: issue resolved,, i have forgotten to add the dependency in pom.xml ..silly me

Comment: good news ! why putting quartz tag ?